# Executing SQL queries using terraform in GITLAB CI after resource creation in VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, gitlab-ci, amazon-vpc

I'm trying to execute sql queries using the following script

```
resource "null_resource" "db_setup" {
  triggers = {
    file = filesha1("${path.module}/test.sql")
  }
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "psql -h '${aws_rds_cluster.rds_cluster}' -p 5432 -U '${rds_cluster.master_username}' -d dbaname -f 'test.sql' -W '${random_password}'"
  }
}
```

I got the following error

```
Error: local-exec provisioner error

with module.rds-db.null_resource.db_setup,
on ../modules/rds-db/db.tf line 158, in resource "null_resource" "db_setup":
provisioner "local-exec" {
Error running command 'psql -V': exit status 127. Output: /bin/sh: psql:not found
```

psql is already installed and path is set in pipeline.

```
  - apk add postgresql postgresql-client
  - psql -V
  - apk add --update util-linux
  - whereis psql
  - export PATH=/usr/bin/psql:$PATH
```

Comment: You are running terraform in your local or in gitlab-ci runner? You should install psql in your runner

Comment: I have already installed it

Answer (score 1):

First, note that `PATH` is supposed to reference *folders* (and `/usr/bin` is probably already on `$PATH`), not executable (like `/usr/bin/psql`).

Second, since a [Terraform `local-exec` provisionner](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/resources/provisioners/local-exec)  invokes a process on the machine running Terraform, not on the resource, check if that machine is indeed the same as your GitLab runner (where you have added `psql`).
Change your command with `echo $PATH; whereis psql`.
(Provisioners are [described as "last resort"](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/resources/provisioners/syntax#provisioners) though)

Comment: It works, now the issue is with rds which is inside vpc so connection is refused, security group allows all traffic also public access is set to true.

Comment: @Shubham OK, that would be better addressed in a separate question. This one seems resolved.